# Include dependencies from Spring XML using maven-bundle-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, osgi, bundle

I'm using maven-bundle-plugin to create MANIFEST.MF. It works fine with dependencies detected in java code, but it ignores the content of spring XML. For example, I have the following declarations:

```
  <context:mbean-export />

  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

  <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform"
      value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
  </bean>
```

So, obviously, my bundle need to import packages `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support`, `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor`, `org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database` and some package for MBeans processor which I even don't know.

From what I can remember, in a project I was participating, we were using Spring and maven-bundle-plugins and all dependencies detection was working fine, so it looks like something is missing in my configuration. I need to somehow inform bundle plugin which XML file it should analyse.

How to make bundle plugin detect dependencies from spring XML?

Here is my bundle plugin configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-resources</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>manifest</goal>
        </goals>

        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Which version of the maven-bundle-plugin do you use?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider mvn -Dplugin=org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin help:describe have told me, 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the maven-bundle-plugin recognizes plain spring contexts. I know it works with blueprint contexts. Anyway make sure your spring context is placed in META-INF/spring. It will only be recognized in this location.

In any case using spring in OSGi is not really supported anymore. The only production ready way was spring dm and this project is dead. There is a experimental support for full spring in Aries blueprint but it is not yet production grade.

The proven way in OSGi is to use blueprint (for example Aries blueprint). Since quite some time now there is also a maven plugin to create the blueprint xml during the build. So in your source you only use annotations.

See [Karaf Tutorial Part 1](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist)

Comment: Yeah, but in case spring context is not in META-INF/spring, is it possible to inform bundle plugin, to use other location?

Comment: You can set your spring xml location in the Manifest header Spring-Context. See http://docs.spring.io/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/app-deploy.html